# Wordpress - Don't display posts which were already displayed in another loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I hace 2 sections on my site: first is for popular posts (based on views) and the second section is for the recent posts.
If the post is already in the popular posts section, I don't want it to be displayed in the "Recent posts" section. Below is my code. In the first loop I've created an array to store all post ID's which are in that section. In the second loop I check if the id is in that array (may be not the best solution). 
For some reason it only works with the first duplicate, even though `$cont` becomes `true` required amount of times(I checked with `echo`). So what gives?

```
 <?php
    $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
    $counter=0;
    $post_ids = array();
    while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post(); 
        $postID = get_the_ID();
        $post_ids[$counter] = $postID;
     ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php   endwhile; ?>

    <?php $myquery = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=6');
    while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
    <?php $post_ids_length = count($post_ids); ?>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $post_ids_length; $i++) {
            if ($post_id == $post_ids[$i]) {
                $cont = "true";
            } else {
                $cont = "false";
            }
    } ?>
    <?php if ($cont == "true") {
        continue;
    } ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class=""><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your Second Query as below:

```
$args2 = array('post__not_in' => $post_ids,'posts_per_page' => 6 );
$myquery = new WP_query($args2);
```

And then just iterate over the result using the While loop.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I'm curios why my code didn't worked, do you have any idea why?

Comment: your code is wrong, because when you find an id equal to the popular id you do not exit from for loop, so you continue and if it's not the last in the array the $cont variable will be set to false in next loop. so you code works for only one post which is the last id in the array. your code works if you add 'break;' after '$cont = "true";'

Comment: @kulan I would recommend to write optimize code, if there is an option to pass in query itself, then we should not go for the custom implemention.